# SSIS derived column comma delimiter and tab

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a problem: I have a `.csv` file and I upload in set a flat file source and set it tab delimited because the `.csv` contains:

```
first name, last name[tab]email
```

In Visual Studio 2008 Enterprise, I don't have a token function.

Like this:

[image]

The email is okay and now I need to separate data column that delimit comma.

I tried to use a derived column like this:

[image]

The name is okay but the last name causes an error.

```
SUBSTRING(datosna, 1, FINDSTRING(datosna, ",", 1) - 1) 
SUBSTRING(datosna, FINDSTRING(datosna, ",", 1) + 1, FINDSTRING(datosna, ",", 2) - 1 - FINDSTRING(datosna, ",", 1) + 1 - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LEFT and RIGHT functions like this:

Surname:

```
LEFT(datosna,FINDSTRING(datosna,",",1) - 1)
```

Name:

```
RIGHT(datosna],(LEN(datosna) - FINDSTRING(datosna,",",1)))
```